# Autofac - callback when type is not registered

Tags: c#, autofac

It is possible?
I'd like to achieve something like this;

```
cntBld.RegisterNotRegisteredCallback(type => return /* custom factory of type */);
```

I mean - if type is not registered explicite I would like to create instance of my own.

Comment: If you could just create an instance....why wouldn't you do that and register it in the first place?

Comment: Because some specific instances is created by external factory. I'd like to avoid perform manual registration of many types across many assemblies. In Windsor I could use SubDepedencyResolver. But I cannot find similar option in autofac.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me. If you know ahead of time what dependencies are needed, you can register them and not have to deal with a clunky architecture.

Comment: @mason don't have to make sense; ) I just ask for specific Autofac feature that can be achievied in other container like Windsor, I'll ask for architecture next time.

Comment: Yes, it does have to make sense. Do you want to write good code built on solid architectural principles and works well? Or do you just want to write code that's brittle and inefficient and "kinda works"? You appear to be asking about an XY Problem.

Comment: @mason sometimes you work with architecture that is not written by you and have hand tied up with corpo-libraries that you cannot change.

Comment: Again, what you're asking *does not make sense*. If you have a way of resolving dependencies after you realize that they're not registered, then you could have just register them properly in the first place. Nothing you've said here changes that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Does the external factory you mentioned use Autofac? If not, your question does not make sense and the solution would be:

```
builder.Register(c => externalFactory.Instance).As<Whatever>();
```

If the external factory you mentioned uses Autofac, the external instance should be resolvable by the component context which is passed to the Register method:

```
builder.Register(c => {
    var externalThing = c.Resolve<IExternalThing>() ?? new ExternalThing();
    return externalThing;
}).As<Whatever>();
```